# Unable to filter with POST request value Django

Tags: django

If I set integer value `(product = 1)` then it's working fine instead of id, when I give id then the response is empty.

```
 id = request.POST.get("product")
 attrs = ProductAttributes.objects.filter(product=id).values('product', 'size__name')
 return JsonResponse(list(attrs), safe=False)
```

This way:

```
id = int(request.POST.get("product"))
```

getting error:

```
TypeError at /purchase-order/ajax/load-attrs/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/purchase-order/ajax/load-attrs/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
Exception Location: D:\MEGA\djangoprojects\myprojects\accpack\views\purchase_order.py, line 76, in load_attrs
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\webapp\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['D:\\MEGA\\djangoprojects\\myprojects',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\envs\\webapp\\lib\\site-packages\\astroid\\brain']
```

Comment: Have you tried `print`ing your value of `id` to check that it really is equal to what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, `print(id)` is `1` but it's a string. If it is an integer then probably the problem will not happened.

Comment: try,  `id = int(request.POST.get("product"))` see if this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST.get("product")` will be a string, but it probably needs to be an integer.

The error in your question occurs when this value is equal to `None` (e.g. it hasn't been submitted as part of your POST request). You should handle this separately.

```
id_str = request.POST.get("product")
try:
    id = int(id_str)
except TypeError:
    # Here you will need to decide what to do
    # if no id is supplied. Maybe raise Http404?
```

(Looking at the error message. I would note further that you are sending a `GET` request, but this view clearly expects a `POST`. Maybe use the [`require_POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) decorator.)

Comment: I have tried it this way but it shows an error. Mentioning the error I update my post. Please take a look.

Comment: @AbzalAli I have updated my answer to reflect your updated question :)

Comment: UnboundLocalError at /purchase-order/ajax/load-attrs/
local variable 'id' referenced before assignment

Comment: That'll be because you've continued onto the code `attrs = ProductAttr...` which uses `id`. But it's not defined. The point is, if `id` is `None` you can't continue on the "happy path". You have to do something else. Raise a 404 or 400 to say that view hasn't been given the information it needs.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The problem is with the data that is being sent to that view, so it should return an error in that case. Or do something else, return a nice message to the user saying what's wrong.

Comment: But the issue isn't with the view, it's with the request that is being sent to it